# How to prevent UIView from being resized to fit ScrollView height (autoresizing disabled)?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

I'm writing a PDF reader using vfr-reader library. To display two pages in landscape i'm rendering each page into its own view, then add these two views to a container view, then add container view to a scroll view. Each view's autoresizingMask is set to UIViewAutoresizingNone, contentMode is UIViewContentModeRedraw, autoresizingSubviews is set to 'NO' for all views.

But still somehow container view is autoresized to fit scroll view's height, and I don't know where is this happening. I care about this because, when autoresizing container view, it's width becomes larger than screen width, and I cannot scroll to the next two pages with a single swipe (two swipes are needed), which sucks. What am I missing?

*EDIT* gonna add some come if it helps. In the ViewController I create a Scroll View with following options:

```
theScrollView = [[ReaderScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
theScrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
theScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
theScrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
theScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
theScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
theScrollView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
theScrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
theScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
theScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
theScrollView.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
theScrollView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:theScrollView];
```

When I'm drawing pages I'm adding an UIView to the Scroll View, which is being initiated this way:

```
if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))
{
    self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
    self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;       
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    theScrollView = [[ReaderScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds]; // Not sure about this part - why is the 2nd scroll view added?
// this is the way its done in vfr reader

    theScrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
    theScrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
    theScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    theScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    theScrollView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
    theScrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    theScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    theScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    theScrollView.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
    theScrollView.bouncesZoom = YES;
    theScrollView.delegate = self;

    theContentView = [[ReaderContentPage alloc] initWithURL:fileURL page:page password:phrase landscape:(BOOL)isLandscape position:FALSE];
    CGRect viewRect = CGRectZero;
    viewRect.size.width = theContentView.bounds.size.width;
    viewRect.size.height = theContentView.bounds.size.height;    


    if( isLandscape){
        NSLog(@"Landscape detected in content view");
        if (theContentView == NULL)
        {
            theContentView = [[ReaderContentPage alloc] initWithURL:fileURL page:(page+1) password:phrase landscape:(BOOL)isLandscape position:FALSE];
            theContentView2 = NULL;
            viewRect.size.width = theContentView.bounds.size.width;
            viewRect.size.height = theContentView.bounds.size.height;    
        } else {
            if (page == 1)
                theContentView2 = NULL;
            else
                theContentView2 = [[ReaderContentPage alloc] initWithURL:fileURL page:(page+1) password:phrase landscape:(BOOL)isLandscape position:TRUE];
            if (theContentView2 != NULL)
               viewRect.size.width = theContentView.bounds.size.width*2;
        }            

    }       
    if (theContentView != nil) // Must have a valid and initialized content view
    {

        theContainerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];


        theContainerView.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
        theContainerView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        theContainerView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;            
        theContainerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
        theContainerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


        theScrollView.contentSize = theContentView.bounds.size; // Content size same as view size


        theScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake((0.0f - CONTENT_INSET), (0.0f - CONTENT_INSET));
        theScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(CONTENT_INSET, CONTENT_INSET, CONTENT_INSET, CONTENT_INSET);

        theThumbView = [[ReaderContentThumb alloc] initWithFrame:theContentView.bounds]; // Page thumb view           

        [theContainerView addSubview:theThumbView]; // Add the thumb view to the container view

        [theContainerView addSubview:theContentView]; // Add the content view to the container view

        if(( isLandscape) && (theContentView2 != NULL)){            
             [theContainerView addSubview:theContentView2]; // Add the content view to the container view

        }           



        [theScrollView addSubview:theContainerView]; // Add the container view to the scroll view

        [self updateMinimumMaximumZoom]; // Update the minimum and maximum zoom scales

        theScrollView.zoomScale = theScrollView.minimumZoomScale; // Zoom to fit
    }

    [self addSubview:theScrollView]; // Add the scroll view to the parent container view   

    [theScrollView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];

    self.tag = page; // Tag the view with the page number
}

return self;
```

And ReaderContentPage is created this way:

```
if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))
    {
        self.autoresizesSubviews = NO;

        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO;
        self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;     
        self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        view = self; // Return self
    }
```

Comment: Have you successfully done the 2page pdf on landscape here @Spail?

Comment: Yes, but in a kinda retarded way. Hopefully I will return to this app soon and do it properly.

Answer (score 2):

In the function `updateMinimumMaximumZoom` in the class `ReaderContentView`:

The calculation of the zoomscale to fit the screen is done with single view, but in landscape it should be calculated form theContainerView.

Try replacing this code

`CGFloat zoomScale = ZoomScaleThatFits(targetRect.size, theContentView.bounds.size);`

with

`CGFloat zoomScale = ZoomScaleThatFits(targetRect.size, theContainerView.bounds.size);`

Comment: in a double page mode for landscape, for the same project (vfr / reader pdf), how do manage to go to next page when a swipe is done.

For example am on page 1, and i have 2 pages showing in the theContainerView, when I make a swipe i want to load page 3 and 4. Currently when i make the swipe it shows me page 2 and 3. How to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a contentMode property in UIScrollView, change it to UIViewContentModeCenter or something else to prevent resizing.

Comment: Not sure which code is needed, but added a lot to my initial post

Comment: For sure, you don't need second scroll view. And fix it:
`self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;`
And I see "Each view's autoresizingMask is set to UIViewAutoresizingNone" in post and `theScrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;` in the code (and for some other views too).