# vfr reader 2 page landscape

Tags: ios, pdf

I'm currently using VFR Reader. And I'm really stuck of displaying 2 pages when on landscape orientation. However, I found this [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900583/how-to-prevent-uiview-from-being-resized-to-fit-scrollview-height-autoresizing), and I tried using the code there and successfully displayed 2 pages side by side. But the problem is it still shows the pages already shown in the previous page. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

In VFR reader there is one content view for each page in all orientation which has single page. I have tried changing content view for landscape mode and potrait mode differently by creating new content view( with 2 page) and showing it on landscape orientation.which can be helpful.
You can include two pages in content view by creating two instance of readercontentpage in readercontentview and framing them side by side in single view.

For reference you can go to this [link](http://www.iostechnik.com/post/45340014906/how-to-show-dual-page-in-landscape-mode-in-vfr-reader)