# iPhone sdk how to implement two page view with vfr reader in landscape mode?

Tags: iphone, pdf, vfr-reader

How to add two page view in vfr reader? i got the following post for that,

[How to prevent UIView from being resized to fit ScrollView height (autoresizing disabled)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900583/how-to-prevent-uiview-from-being-resized-to-fit-scrollview-height-autoresizing)

But i couldn't understand that much. Can anyone of you please suggest some idea's or sample codes to implement the two page view with vfr reader in landscape mode?

Thanks in advance.